# How to use value from table to navigate while loop?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I would like to use particular value from table as condition in while loop.

I have the following table

```
Type | Amount  
--------------
aa         50         
aa         50         
aa         50         
aa         50         
aa         50         
bb         null       
aa         100        
aa         100        
aa         100
aa         100
..
aa         80        
aa         100        
aa         90
aa         100
aa         80        
aa         100        
aa         100
aa         100
```

I need to add status column.

```
declare 
cursor c1 
is
SELECT
  Type                                
, Amount                                                                         
FROM Table;

begin

while c1.Type = 'bb' LOOP

INSERT INTO TABLE_2
(
Type, Amount, Status
)
VALUES
(
Table.Type, Table.Amount, Status ); 

END LOOP;
END;
```

Table_2 has the additionally Status column and I would like to insert to Table_2 'X' to Status column where the condition from while is not achived but when loop encountered value 'bb' in Type column insert 'Y' to Status but only for 10 rows, rest should be inserted 'Z' value.

The result of loop:

```
Type | Amount | Status  
------------------------
aa         50      X   
aa         50      X   
aa         50      X   
aa         50      X   
aa         50      X   
bb         null    Z   (1)
aa         100     Z   (2)
aa         100     Z   (3)
aa         100     Z   (4)
aa         100     Z   (5)
..             
aa         80      Z   (8)   
aa         100     Z   (9)   
aa         90      Z   (10)
aa         100     Y
aa         80      Y  
aa         100     Y   
aa         100     Y
aa         100     Y
```

Comment: Your Y and Z in the output don't seem to match your description. But your original data doesn't seem to have anything to order by, so how do you expect to tell when the condition applies?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Poole, your sample data/result does not agree with your explanation.

In any case, you don't need a cursor or loop. Below query should do the trick with some amendments depending on the condition for the status.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_2
SELECT
  Type                                
, Amount
, case Type when 'bb' then 'X' else 'Z' end                                                                       
FROM Table
```

Comment: I need to use a loop because i wrote only a clipping of database and i have more complicated cases in the table so i need to go row by row to identify them.
The question is how to use value from particular filed in table to navigate while loop? @stubs

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are aiming for.
You can amend the case statement to handle more complicated cases
e.g.    
              case when Type  = 'bb' then 'X' 
                      when Type  = 'aa'  and amount <= 50 then 'Z' 
                      else 'Y' end

Comment: not exactly ..when the query encounters cases e.g. Type = 'bb' then 'X' but the should be set for next 12 months when Type = 'aa' then 'Z' and set status for 6 months. I think it is not possible using case statement in modification clause. @stubs